# asp.net Web API not routing http GET with query parameters

Tags: asp.net-web-api, http-get, query-string

I have two controller actions defined in my AgenciesController as follows:

```
 public IEnumerable<AgencyDTO> GetAll()
        {

        }

        public AgencyDTO GetForLocation(double lat, double lon)
        {

        }
```

When I submit the following HTTP GET request

```
  http://localhost:13057/api/agencies?lat=45.4214&lon=-75.6919
```

the second method that accepts two double input paramters is never invoked.  Instead GetAll is always invoked.  This is using the default WebApiConfig which from my understanding should be sufficient.  I tried using strings for parameters lat and lon and it did not make a difference.

What am I missing?

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue with how the HTTP GET request was being submitted.  I was using cURL to submit the request and it was stripping out the query parameters after the URL.  I needed to soround the entire URL with double quotes as follows:

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:13057/api/agencies?lat=45.4214&lon=-75.6919"
```

In hindsight, I should have indicated ths request was being submitted or tried submitting via the browser before posting the question.